# How get the id after sending a request with php and save to the Database?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to build a something that just allow me to send friendship request as on facebook. What i just made the process to search for a new person, find him. so i am getting his name, city and country and at side there is a button for sending a new friendship require. so when i am clicking on it i am just storing my id, the date of when i sent the require but i didn't store the id of the person i am sending the friendship request to store in my database. this is my problem. to store the id of the person that i am sending a request of frienship
Someone can help me.i just passed 4 day on it and i could not find a solution.There is something escaping me.

Here is the code:
this field is to get a person to send the invitation. I used jquery to do an auto complete

```
 <form class="navbar-form" method="POST" action="competition.php">
        <div class="input-group no-border">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLocalidade" name="Name"  
                placeholder="chercher quelqu'un pour défier...">
                    <button type="submit" name="btn-search" class="btn btn- 
                           default btn-round btn-just-icon">
                          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                          <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                    </button>
         </div>
     </form>
```

After clicking, that just bring the person i am looking for with his name, city, and a button t=for sending a friendship request:

```
 <?php

              require_once '../database/db.php';// calling the database with db_configuration
              
     if (isset($_POST['btn-search'])) //if the button of submit is pressed do:
         {

              $IdToFriend = $_POST["IdToFriend"]; 
              $Sex = $_SESSION["Sex"];
              $A0_User_IdUser = $_SESSION["IdUser"];
              $query = $conn->query("SELECT U.IdUser as IdUser, U.Name as Name, U.Sex as Sex, M.Country as Country, M.City as City FROM a0_user  U
              INNER JOIN  a0_medicalform M
              on U.IdUser = M.A0_User_IdUser
              WHERE Name LIKE '$IdToFriend' limit 4
              ");
        
         $result = $conn->query("Select count(IdUser) from a0_user ");
         $count = $result->rowcount();
      
        
         //ÇA FONCTIONNE PAS DU TOUT
         if(!$count)
         {
           echo"<div class='text-center' style='color:white;'><h3>Aucune recherche trouvée! <img src='../assets/img/loadRun.gif' width='50'></h3></div>";
         } 
                while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                  if($count) 
                  {
                    echo" <div class='text-center' style='color:white;'>
                               <h3>Votre recherche a donné cette précedente liste:</h3>
                          </div>";
                  } 
                    
                  echo "
                   <div class='list-group'>
                  <a href='#' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'>";
                  if( $row['Sex'] == 'M')
                  {
                      echo"
                              <img class='img rounded-circle' src='../assets/img/man-profile.png' alt='man' width='80px;' />
                           ";
                  } 

                
              else{
                echo"
                <img class='img rounded-circle' src='../assets/img/woman-profile.jpg' alt='woman' width='80px;'/>
                    ";
                  }
                  echo" <i><b class='ml-2'> {$row['Name']}</b></i>
                     <i class='ml-5'><b>Habite à: {$row['Country']}, {$row['City']}</b></i> ";?>
                   <form method='POST' action='friendshipRequest.php'>
               
                       <button type="submit" id=<?php echo $row['IdUser']?> class='btn btn-primary float-right mt-4'>Envoyez un Défi</button>
                        
                    
                  </form><?php 
                  
                 
              }
            }   
          
            
         
            ?>
```

HERE IS JUST WHERE I SEND THE REQUISITION TO SAVE IN THE DATABASE:

```
<?php 
session_start(); //starting a session with nuvens application
require_once '../database/db.php';// calling the database with db_configuration


  $A0_User_IdUser = $_SESSION["IdUser"];
  $IdAskedPerson = $_POST['IdUser'];

  
  if (!$IdAskedPerson) {
    echo "<script>alert('IdAskedPerson est vide'); window.location = 'competition.php' </script>"; //if it is empty return to the same page default.php
  } 

  
  else {
  
      try{
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO a4_relationship (A0_User_IdUser,IdAskedPerson,DateRequestSending) 
   VALUES (:A0_User_IdUser,:IdAskedPerson,now())'); // do insert with row_name setting from the database 
  $stmt->execute(array(':A0_User_IdUser' =>$A0_User_IdUser,
                       ':IdAskedPerson'=>$IdAskedPerson,
                         ));
  
  echo "<script>alert('Enregistré avec succes!'); window.location='index.php'</script>";//after do insert, take me to the page default.php
 }

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  
  }
  }
  
  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the ID of the last inserted record. If that's the question you are asking..
You can use the `lastInsertId` function that is part of the PDO library

`$conn->lastInsertId();`

Comment: 0


i want to build a something that just allow me to send friendship request as on facebook. What i just made the process to search for a new person, find him. so i am getting his name, city and country and at side there is a button for sending a new friendship require. so when i am clicking on it i am just storing my id, the date of when i sent the require but i didn't store the id of the person i am sending the friendship request to store in my database. this is my problem. to store the id of the person that i am sending a request of frienship

Comment: Since you are sending a request to a Profile, that profile object should already have the id stored somewhere, sometimes it's stored in a hidden input for example. Else you can also get the id of the friend request by doing a db query for that Profile. Since I'm assuming  you are working on your own site, make sure when you display Profiles, store profile id somewhere you can easily grab it after, Like a hidden input that I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes you are right i just did it now store it to a javascript variavel to see if it realy take the id. but i dont have any idea of how i have to store it to my database. if u can help that will be great. that why i just put my code over there